# Selenium-IDE 2.5 cannot identify objects or links inside a frame

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm using `Selenium-IDE 2.5` and `Firefox 26.0`, the problem with `Selenium-IDE 2.5` is that it doesn't identify or locate a link or any objects inside a `frame` and I couldn't write the proper code for that.

When I use `Selenium-IDE 2.0.0` version it can identify the link and object inside a frame. Unfortunately I couldn't find the path to download `IDE 2.0.0`.

I would be very much obliged if you can help me with a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

try to use `selectFrame` in your steps and set the name of frame.

First, you select the frame and after you keep doing your steps.

Hugs,
Vin.